# AJAX não faz leitura da seleção do calendário Datepicker

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estou usando esse código para uma verificado datas no banco de dados sem fazer o refresh da pagina com o php. Mas o AJAX só faz leitura do campo quando eu digito manualmente no input data, quando faço a seleção pelo calendário datapicker ele não realiza a chamada.

Alguém tem ideia de como solucionar esse problema?

```
<form method="POST" id="form-pesquisa" action="">
            <label>Data: </label>
            <input wicket: type="text" name="pesquisa" readonly="true"  id="pesquisa">
            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></input>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                  $( "#pesquisa" ).datepicker({
                                        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                                        daysOfWeekDisabled: "0",
                                        todayHighlight: true,   
                                        todayBtn: true,
                                        startDate: 'd', 
                                        autoclose: true,
                                        zIndexOffset: 99999999,
                                        language: "pt-BR"
                                    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
                                    $("#pesquisa").datepicker("getDate");
                                    </script>
                
        </form>
```

```
$(function(){
    $("#pesquisa").keyup(function(){
        //Recuperar o valor do campo    
        var pesquisa = $(this).val();
        
        //Verificar se há algo digitado
        if(pesquisa != ''){
            var dados = {
                palavra : pesquisa
            }
            $.post('proc_pesq_user.php', dados, function(retorna){
                //Mostra dentro da ul os resultado obtidos 
                $(".resultado").html(retorna);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite pc27reis,

Como você não informou, acredito estar utilizando este plugin:

http://yhnavein.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/#options

Independente do plugin utilizando, muitos deles possuem eventos internos que você pode chamar para efetuar o que você precisa, tente verificar a documentação do plugin que você esta utilizando, segue um exemplo:

```
/**
 * Este plugin datepicker possui o evento changeDate
 * que é executado quando ocorre a alteração
 * da data, ao selecionar uma no calendário
 */
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(e){
        alert(e.date.toString());
    });
```

No seu caso você poderia fazer algo como isso:

```
$("#pesquisa").datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0",
    todayHighlight: true,   
    todayBtn: true,
    startDate: 'd', 
    autoclose: true,
    zIndexOffset: 99999999,
    language: "pt-BR"
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
  var dados = {
     palavra: e.date.toString()
  }
  $.post('proc_pesq_user.php', dados, function(retorna) { 
    $(".resultado").html(retorna);
  });
});
```

Espero ter lhe ajudado.